# Remove default seperator mule transformer

Tags: csv, mule, dataweave

I am trying to write data from Salesforce to a CSV file.

I am using Data Weave transformer to transform data, but by default it takes  "\" as  a separator and is causing all  problems in my CSV.

[image: CSV issue]

My transformer code is simple one

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/csv
---
payload
```

Is there any option by which we can disable '\' as a separator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dataweave, for a **CSV** transformation, you can configure some options:

> **Separator**: separator character for parsing the values. `default=','`
>
> **Quote**: quote character. `default=" "`
>
> **Escape**: escape char for quotes. `default=/`
>
> **Header**: When true, the header will be parsed and used as field names. `default=true`

#### How to configure?

```
%output application/csv header=true, separator=",", escape="/"
```

I think you are having a problem with the `escape` default value. You should change it.

> Take a look to the documentation: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation#input-directive

Comment: I tried with this ' %output application/csv header=true, separator="," , escape="\\", quote =" " ' but still  the same result

Comment: is there any way we can enclose  each field data into double quotes

Comment: Develop your script, so, you will be able to do something like:  {"result":{"Name":payload.Name replace "\\" with "-", "Email":payload.Email}}

Comment: in mule there is no way to encode the string into a quotes?

Comment: there is data in some columns which contains ',' so it separated  out in a CSV, but I don't want that,  if we enclose in double quotes, it still includes a '\' in the data with a comma

Answer (score 0):

The default escape character(character that escapes quotes) is /. In order to change it as per requirements, you must :

Go to the XML editor and then, you must set these up as child elements of the dataweave component, like in the example below:

```
<dw:input-payload doc:sample="list_csv.csv" mimeType="text/csv" >
    <dw:reader-property name="escape" value="|"/>
</dw:input-payload>
```

Here you can set the 'escape' to be anything as you wish, by setting its value accordingly.